# Xml formatting using Node

Tags: ruby

Following is the method used to write an entry to xml file

```
def write_entry(entry)
  node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new("url", @xml_document)
  node["loc"]= entry[:url]
  node["lastmod"]= entry[:lastmod].to_s
  node["changefreq"] =  entry[:frequency].to_s
  node["priority"] = entry[:priority].to_s
  node.to_xml
end
```

The entry looks like this:

```
<urlset>
  <url loc="http:`enter code here`//www.experteer.co.uk/vacaturebank/banen/vacatures/xing-ag" lastmod="2011-11-23 16:58:27 UTC" changefreq="0.8" priority="monthly"/>
</urlset>
```

I want the entry of xml to be like this

```
<urlset>
  <url>
    <loc> http://www.experteer.co.uk/vacaturebank/banen/vacatures/xing-ag </loc>
    <lastmod> 2011-11-23 16:58:27 UTC </lastmod>
    <changefreq> 0.8 </changefreq>
    <priority> monthly </priority>
  </url>
 </urlset>
```

Is it possible with using Node or I have to use Builder?
If possible with Node Then how?
and If I have to use Builder it writes header for each entry how can I handle that it dont write header for each entry.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910457/ruby-modify-an-xml-file-in-one-pass

Comment: This is something different what i m looking for :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `<<` or `add_child` to append children nodes to a node.

```
def write_entry(entry)
  url = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( "url" , @xml_document )
  %w{loc lastmod changefreq priority}.each do |node|
    url <<  Nokogiri::XML::Node.new( node, @xml_document ).tap do |n| 
              n.content = entry[ node.to_sym ] 
            end  
  end
  url.to_xml
end
```

For this to work correctly, you have to change `entry[:url]` to `entry[:loc]`. and `entry[:frequency]` to `entry[:changefreq]`, which shouldn't be a bad thing (it's best to have the same name for the same thing everywhere, isn't it ?).

Alternatively, if your `entry` hash only contains what you need to convert to xml, use `entry.each do |key,value|` instead of the array.

Comment: u r great :) Thanks a zillion